# What is the right sentence for this context?

Tags: idiomatic-language

**1)** I am very pleased for the opportunity to work with you next summer.

**2)** I am really pleased about the opportunity to work with you next summer.

**3)** I am glad you give me an opportunity to work with you next summer.

Which one is more appropriate and sounds natural? Also, I would be happy to see your sample sentences for this context.

Answer (score 2):

Of the given sentences, #3 seems most natural and plausible to me. "I am very pleased **for** the opportunity" seems unusual and perhaps awkward to me. "about the opportunity" does not seem to have the tone that I think is wanted.

I would suggest:

> I am very pleased to have the opportunity to work with you next summer.